# Get document properties on IBM BPM 8.6 using REST API

Tags: business-process-management, filenet-p8, ibm-bpm, filenet

I'm trying to retrieve a document's properties store in IBM BPM document store but I couldn't find any API to call, is there any workaround to achieve this ? 
I'm trying to copy documents from **IBM Document Store** to **Filenet** using **Java**.

I was able to get documents of a snapshot using:

> /rest/bpm/wle/v1/process/

and getting document's content using:

> /portal/jsp/ecmDocument?operation=ajax_getDocumentContent

but I also need the properties of this document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a service inside your Process App that retrieves these properties and then called it via Rest API